# php/mysql UPDATE where id = blah

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a site where you can send greeting messages via php to a mysql server, and an admin login page. In the admin login page, it shows all of the messages with a status either pending, rejected or accepted with the buttons reject and accept next to each message.
Currently, whenever I hit "accept" or "reject" ALL of the messages become rejected or accepted in the database. I'd like to have the buttons call the script with a parameter which is the id of the message they're accepting/rejecting but I honestly don't know the proper syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT name, location, message, status FROM messages ORDER by status ";
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) 
{
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) 
    {
        $name = $query_row['name'];
        $location = $query_row['location'];
        $message = $query_row['message'];
        $status = $query_row['status'];    

        echo '<form method="POST" action="login.php">';
        echo 'From: '.$name.'<br>Location: '.$location.'<br>Status: '.$status.'<br>Message: '.$message.'<br><br>';
?>

<input type="submit" value="Approve" name="accept">
<input type="submit" value="Reject" name="reject"></form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['accept'])) 
{
    echo 'Accepted!';
    $updateAccept = "UPDATE messages SET status = 'a'"; 
    mysql_query($updateAccept);   
};

if (isset($_POST['reject'])) 
{
    echo 'Rejected!';
    $updateAccept = "UPDATE messages SET status = 'r'"; 
    mysql_query($updateAccept);
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... WHERE` you need a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: add a hidden field with the record's id, read that with `$_POST`and apply it to your sql-query.

Comment: And please consider switching to mysqli or PDO instead of deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: So where is the problem? Just add a `WHERE` clause and be done with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind a hidden field with each submit button like this

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Whatever" name="trigger_update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_to_be_updated" value="<?php echo 'pass your id here'; ?>" />
</form>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['trigger_update'])) {
      //Do sanitization according to your needs
      mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE tbl_name SET column_name = 'whatever' WHERE id = {$_POST['id_to_be_updated']}");
   }
?>
```

Comment: While yes... at the same time, no.  Type cast the ID or something, don't put raw `post` data into a SQL statement.

Comment: @Jon That's why I mentioned to sanitize according to his needs :)

Comment: Haha, true, but you show the `$_POST` in the update, I just thought you should show a reassignment and then the 'sanitize to your needs' type of thing. =]

Comment: Hello Mr.Alien. You post helps, it's essentially what I wanted to do: have the WHERE = $_POST approve/reject button. However, I'm fairly new to php, and I'm not quite sure what you meant by 'pass your id here' and "Do sanitization according to your needs". Is Jon saying you shouldn't post raw post data in an SQL statement, or you outright can't? Thanks in advance, great help so far

Comment: @user2280332 `Pass Your ID HERE` means when you loop your records, echo the id value in that hidden field, and sanitize the data means though the data will be predefined by you in this case, it is likely that any bad value gets posted with a quote or something else which you need to sanitize, so I've mentioned to sanitize the data always before posting/altering data in your database...also `mysql_()` is deprecated, start using `mysqli_()` or `PDO` :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `WHERE` clause in your UPDATE statement:

```
 $updateAccept = "UPDATE messages SET status = 'a' WHERE id = '$id'";
```